# Google charts devuelve grafico antes de display div

Tags: ajax

tengo un problemilla al realizar una llamada ajax como la siguiente. La funcion grafico(codigo) me dibuja un gráfico de google charts. El problema es que el div id="chart" esta en el html de respuesta de la llamada ajax. Si la llamada del gráfico la realiza antes me indica que es nulo div id="chart" y no devuelve el gráfico. Mejor forma para solucionarlo?

He probado a llamar la función grafico(codigo) después de mostrar el contenedor pero sigo teniendo el problema....

```js
$.ajax({                    
                url:"buscar_info.php",
                type:"POST",
                data:codigo,
                dataType:"html",
                success:
                    function(respuesta)
                            {     
                            grafico(codigo);
                            $("#contenedor").show('fast');
                            $("#contenedor").html(respuesta);
                            }
                    });
```

Gracias. Un saludo

Comment: por favor, podrías añadir el código de la función grafico()?

Answer (score 0):

Nada perdona..he podido acceder ahora con mozilla me marca este error el firebug:

TypeError: google.visualization.Datatable is not a constructor

Te pongo el código de la función gráfico

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart','line']});

function grafico(codigo){
        var codigo=codigo;
         $.ajax({
            url:"buscar_json.php",
            type:"POST",  
            data:codigo_tienda,
            dataType:"json",                  
            success:
            function(resultado){
            
             
                  $("#container_grafico_ventas").show();
                
      var dataVentas=resultado.ventas;
        var dataVentas = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                      dataVentas.addColumn('string', 'Mes');
                      dataVentas.addColumn('number', '2016');
                      dataVentas.addColumn('number', '2017');
     
        dataVentas.addRows([dataSetVentas[0],dataSetVentas[1]]);
  
              var options = {
                    isStacked: 'true',
                      'width':dWidth,
                    'height':400,
                    series: {
                      0: { color: '#E3141C' },   
                      1: { color: '#ff00d4' },
                  }
                 
        };


        var chartVentas = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('grafico_ventas'));
         
        chartVentas.draw(dataVentas, options);
```